# What do we call the front part of a decimal number?

Tags: terminology, real-numbers

I have the following number.

```
23.45
```

There are two parts of this number. **23** and **45**. What is the mathematical name of the **23** part?

Comment: It's called the "integer part." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal

Comment: The $23$ is called [integer part](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerPart.html). The $45$ is called [fractional part](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part).

Comment: I do not understand the so many up votes. But never mind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Often we call 23 the whole or integer part and .45 the decimal or fractional part.

Comment: How about integral instead of integer?

Comment: @Mehrdad I would refrain from using the word integral, just because it has a specific meaning in calculus

Answer (score 4):

According to [this math.stackexchange post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64042/what-are-the-numbers-before-and-after-the-decimal-point-referred-to-in-mathemati), you can also call them the *characteristic* (before) and *mantissa* (after). This what I heard when I was learning about floating point specifications.

Answer (score 3):

According to Wikipedia, it is the integer part or the integral part.

http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal